# Match words from array into a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a cell which contains a description like the one below

"customer enjoys playing cricket and football."

Then on another worksheet I have a list of sports

**Cell / Sport**

- A1: Tennis
- A2: Football
- A3: Golf
- A4: Boxing
- A5: Hockey
- A6: Cricket

I need iterate through the list of sports and match the first sport in the list and then print it. Here are some examples of what I'd like to return.

**Description / Sport** (These are defined under 'Name Manager' as 'SPORT_NAMES')

- "customer enjoys playing cricket and football." / Football (Because Football is in A1 and cricket is only in A6)
- "customer is playing golf today." / Golf
- "shall we play tennis or golf today" / Tennis

**I am able to do it for each cell using the following formula**

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sports!A1,Data!A2)), "Tennis", "")

Thanks,

Kieran

Comment: If you were content with helper columns you could have a separate one for search for each sport and then find the minimum value and do a look up to establish the sport to which it pertains.

Comment: You could concatenate several IFS and IFERROR with SEARCH, starting with your first sport. If SEARCH return error, means that sport does not appear, so use an IFERROR to to another SEARCH. But if SEARCH returns a number, the sport appears, so return the sport searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$6,E1)),0))` - This is an array formula (enter the formula by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar)

By using a double unary operator you convert the `TRUE` / `FALSE` result of `ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$6,E1))` to 0 or 1 respectively.

I then use `MATCH()` as the return value for `INDEX()` to get the appropriate result (which will always be the first occurrance)

[image: example]

Comment: Excellent. Works just as intended and the list of sports can be dynamic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there is a clean and nice way of doing this, but at least, this answer will work.

First of all. I strongly encourage you to list the sports as in my screenshot, with an auxiliary column that shows the importante of each sport. Thay way you can reorder as you want or change positions and remember priority:

[image]

Then, I used this dirty formula to get the results:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IF(SEARCH('LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$2;Hoja1!A1)>0;'LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$2);IF(SEARCH('LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$3;Hoja1!A1)>0;'LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$3));IF(SEARCH('LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$4;Hoja1!A1)>0;'LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$4));IF(SEARCH('LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$5;Hoja1!A1)>0;'LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$5));IF(SEARCH('LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$6;Hoja1!A1)>0;'LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$6));IF(SEARCH('LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$7;Hoja1!A1)>0;'LIST OF SPORTS'!$B$7));"No sports found")
```

And in Sheet1 I get this:

[image]

Hope this can help you out.

Comment: Great thanks, this solution works. I am looking into a way of making it cleaner because the list of sports is due to grow and will likely cause problems in the future. I'm currently looking into `formula arrays` - is this the right approach to making a cleaner solution?

Comment: Not sure if with arrays, but 100% sure if you develop a code in VBA (an UDF) to make this.